Laravel + React checkbox is not enabled and no file is uploaded, the file path is set to null in the database?
In my scenario, when I upload from Postman without a file, it works fine. But the problem is when I try to upload from my frontend, it gives me an error message.
Database table migration :
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('materials_basic_information', function(Blueprint $table){
$table->boolean('msds')->default(0);
            $table->string('msds_file')->nullable();
    });
    }


Error message from the console:

{"message":"The msds file field must be a file. (and 1 more error)","errors":{"msds_file":["The msds file field must be a file.","The msds file field must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf."]}}


Backend code in Laravel:
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::guard('api')->check()){
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'msds_file' => 'nullable|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,pdf|max:2048'
 ]);

// validated, file
   $msdsFile = $request->file('msds_file');

 $uploadedFiles = [];
                // handle the file upload
                foreach ($validatedData as $fieldName => $file) {
                    $uploadedFileName = time() . '_' . $fieldName . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $file->storeAs('public/materialfiles', $uploadedFileName);
                    // Add the uploaded file name to the array
                    $uploadedFiles[$fieldName] = $uploadedFileName;
                }

$result = ProminentTechMaterialsBasicInfoModel::create([
 'msds' => $request->input('msds') === 'true' ? 1 : 0,
'msds_file' => $uploadedFiles['msds_file'] ?? null
     ]);
            return response()->json(['Status' => 'Success', 'message' => 'Materials data inserted successfully'],200);
        }else{
            return Response(['Status' => 'Failed' , 'data' => 'Unauthorized'],401);
        }
    }

Frontend code in React:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const MaterialAddNew = () => {
const [msds, setMsds] = useState(false);
  const [msds_file, setMsds_file] = useState(null);

  const handleMsds_file = (event) => {
    const file_msds_file = event?.target?.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
    setMsds_file(file_msds_file);
  };

 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("msds", msds);
    formData.append("msds_file", msds_file);

 const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    };
 axios
      .post(`${baseAPI}/api/materialsbasicinfo`, formData, { headers })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        toast.success("Material data created successfully");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.request.response);
        toast.error("Failed to create material data");
      });
  };
return (

            <tr className="">
              <td className="font-medium">MSDS</td>
              <td> : </td>
              <td className="py-2">
                <div className="flex">
                  <div className="mx-2">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={msds}
                      onChange={() => {
                        setMsds(!msds);
                      }}
                      className="default:ring-2"
                    />
                  </div>
                  {msds && (
                    <div className="mx-2 my-auto">
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        onChange={handleMsds_file}
                        className="border border-[#499494] py-1 px-2 rounded-sm w-[210px]"
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
   <div className="sm:col-span-12">
          <div className="my-1">
            <button className="bg-[#15445E] px-3 py-1 text-white rounded-sm">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MaterialAddNew;

In the frontend, when the checkbox is enabled and a file is uploaded, the file is uploaded successfully. However, I want the file path to be set to null in the database when the checkbox is not enabled and no file is uploaded.
